# Blueprint CSS Framework/Sticky Footer with IE6 Problem

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, blueprint-css

I'm currently using the [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org) framework setting my width to 910px along with the [sticky footer markup](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com) by Steve Hatcher.

The **problem** I'm getting is that for some reason in only Internet Explorer 6 is that an extra padding/margin of 10px is being added on the right hand side of my #wrap class.

I have uploaded my test site here:

[http://www.prashantraju.com/test](http://prashantraju.com/test/)

Here is a comparison of IE6 vs IE7.

[comaparison http://www.prashantraju.com/test/ie6ie7.gif](http://www.prashantraju.com/test/ie6ie7.gif)

As you can see there is no margin/padding on the right hand side (the red area) with IE7 but in IE6 there is an extra 10px.

Is there a way to fix this - or what the cause of the extra 10px is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can get with FireBug, there is no explicitly width set to the navigation bar, what if you give it a fixed size(same as 910px)?

Edited:

Sorry, given the FireBug css output, I suspect that you are using a inherited element from screen.css from line 101: margin-right:10px;

I reckon that is the cause.

Now that the navigation bar has it own css entry in the stylesheet, maybe you can reassign the margin-right element valut back to zero to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks!

Adding a margin-right:0 on elements which spanned the 910px or 23 columns fixed the extra margin of 10px in IE6.

Comment: Oh, good to hear that :)
Just by the way, you can deal with browser incompatibilities by examining the browser type so to load specific css for that particular browser. IE6 is a headache and bane of me...